# In Posix how is type dev_t getting used?

Tags: c, posix, stat

What I am after is the meaning of such type and what interface can use it.

It is explained in Posix spec that `dev_t` is used for device IDs. However, what device id means for any object described by a path, which can be a file, a directy, a fifo or a physical device?

For example, calling `stat()` shall give you a struct including a member of such type; and you can stat any kinds of object in your file system. The device id should have different meanings for different file types then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only use of `dev_t` in the vast majority of programs (ones which are portable and not connected to a single OS) is to determine that two file names or file descriptors refer to the same underlying file. This is true if and only if the `st_ino` and `st_dev` entries for the two files' `stat` structures match one another.

Basically, `st_dev` tells which "device" (e.g. mounted partition, network share, etc.) the file resides on, and `st_ino` is a unique identifier of the file within the context of a single device.

Comment: Can't you have multiple file systems on one device?

Comment: @user129393192: No, each partition or other virtualized (e.g. loopback) block device is its own device (its own `dev_t` value).

Comment: You mean any file system or other "device" has a `dev_t`? So it's not based on partition?

Comment: @user129393192: Every thing which is mountable has a unique `dev_t`.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there are two `dev_t`-typed fields in [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html):

- `st_dev` is the "[d]evice ID of device containing file", so if two files have the same `st_dev`, they're on the same filesystem.
- `st_rdev` is the device ID of the device denoted by a character or block special file, i.e. the files commonly encountered in `/dev`. It has no meaning for other types of files.

Comment: But you did not explain what the device id is. For a normal file, there is no device associated, then what does the id mean here?

Comment: @MengfeiMurphy: every file exists on some device, be it a disk partition or a network share. That's what `st_dev` designates.

Answer (score 6):

Within the kernel, the dev_t type who is defined in  is used to hold device numbers (major/minor). dev_t is a 32-bit quantity with 12 bits set aside for the major number and 20 for the minor number.

Comment: Yes, my /dev/sda1 `st_rdev` gives 2049, which is true because it is in major 8 min 1

Answer (score 1):

> **NOT** an answer to the question, just update some info about `st_dev`

`dev_t` in current glibc (2.35) is **64-bit**, with 32-bit major and minor numbers. glibc's default encoding is `MMMM Mmmm mmmM MMmm`, where `M` is a hex digit of the `major number` and `m` is a hex digit of the `minor number`. This is backward compatible with legacy systems where dev_t is 16 bits wide, encoded as MMmm. It is also backward compatible with the Linux kernel, which for some architectures uses 32-bit dev_t, encoded as mmmM MMmm.

One can use `major(3)` and `minor(3)` to decompose a `dev_t`:

```bash
$ cat main.c
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        struct stat buf;
        assert(0 == stat(".", &buf));

        printf("Major device ID: %d\n", major(buf.st_dev));
        printf("Minor device ID: %d\n", minor(buf.st_dev));
}

$ gccs main.c && ./a.out
Major device ID: 0
Minor device ID: 39
```