# Comparing to see if file descriptors share an underlying file

Tags: c, file, operating-system, filesystems, file-descriptor

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635702/in-posix-how-is-type-dev-t-getting-used), I see that something like:

```
bool
ref_same_file(int fd1, int fd2)
{
  struct stat stat1, stat2;
  if (!fstat(fd1, &stat1) && !fstat(fd1, &stat2))
    return (stat1.st_dev == stat2.st_dev)
      && (stat1.st_ino == stat2.st_ino);
  perror("fstat");
  exit(errno);
}
```

could see if two file descriptors reference the same file. However, I am not totally clear on the `st_dev`. Is this not the block device? Can a single block device not hold multiple file systems?

I see the [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) states that it makes it uniquely identifiable, but I am wondering how this is possible.

Comment: For a disk device the `st_dev` member identifies not only the disk itself (the *major* device number), but also the partition on the disk (the *minor* device number). A single disk partition can only hold a single filesystem.

Comment: How's that? I had thought that you could have multiple on a single partition.

Comment: Why do you think that? Would it really make sense to have a partition formatted for both NTFS and ext4? How would that even work?

Comment: I'm not sure. I had seen some other threads on it: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463833/can-we-create-two-different-filesystems-on-a-single-partition), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/257800/can-we-create-two-filesystems-on-a-single-partition).

Comment: What the answers in those questions are talking about is to create a *file* that emulates a file-system. With the right driver support those can be mounted and read from or written to as any other drive and filesystem. *But* they are then different devices, with a different major and minor device number. And the file is still a file stored on a primary (actual physical) drive with one single filesystem.

Comment: I believe the accepted answer on the first attempted to demonstrate it, with a real partition, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: That one is very academic and not practically feasible. And as the answer mentions, only one filesystem can be mounted at a time. So even in that highly theoretical situation, you can't have multiple filesystems for a single major/minor device pair at runtime. So the comparison in the shown code will still work.

Comment: @user129393192 When you run `df` on a POSIX system, what's the first column of the output?  It's the **device** the file system resides on...

Comment: Does this mean that the device is not based on partition, but rather file system? What exactly denotes a device in this case? From my understanding, you could have a partition like `/dev/sda1` and also split that into devices, which you can use for “device ids” and individual file systems?